# Prevent table data editing in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Is there any way in Oracle SQL Developer to view table data **read-only** or prevent editing?  When I view the data in a table it lets me edit, and I want to avoid accidentally making a change.  I would expect there to be a way to toggle this somehow, but I haven't found it.  I'm using version 2.1.1.64.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is. Ask your DBA to create a user that only has read access to the TABLES in question and then log in with that user.

The other thing to remember is that if you do edit some data in a data grid in order for the change to written to the database you have to separately commit the change to the database by either issuing a `COMMIT` command in an SQL Worksheet or by clicking on the Green Tick button or pressing <kbd>F11</kbd>.

Pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> Will Rollback Changes that have not been committed.